# ATmega 328p Using crystal with fuses set to "ceramic resonator"

Tags: atmega, crystal, fuses

Would it work in such arrangement?

I'm trying to figure out what mistake I made setting the fuses so that the chip stopped working with SPI programming. I think I set the correct CLKSEL fuses but the SUT fuses I set incorrectly for slowly starting ceramic resonator instead of crystal. Would this still work with a crystal?

Comment: Ceramic resonator oscillators start 10-100x faster than crystal oscillators (because the Q of the resonator is so much lower).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start-up time may not be sufficient for the crystal oscillator to get moving.

Usually the settings for crystal oscillators will work okay with the more forgiving ceramic resonators, but the reverse is **not** true. The datasheet warns in particular about using the shortest start-up time with crystals at all, or the medium start-up time with crystals that are close to the maximum frequency for the chip.

[image]